# Server Access Error when trying to run Play 2.4 project

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt, server

I am working on a Play 2.4 project. After adding a dependency a plugin in my build.sbt and attempting to re-compile the project I received an error indicating 2 unresolved dependencies. I removed the plugin and attempted to re-compile the project again and still received a similar error indicating 1 unresolved dependency rather than 1. I am also unable to create new projects due to receiving similar errors. Fresh clones of the project do not work either and the project was working before I attempted to add the plugin.

Here is the error resulting from trying to run the project

```
[error] Server access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/inject/extensions/guice-assistedinject/4.0/guice-assistedinject-4.0.pom
[warn]  module not found: com.google.inject.extensions#guice-assistedinject;4.0
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/travis/.ivy2/local/com.google.inject.extensions/guice-assistedinject/4.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-launcher-local: tried
[warn]   /home/travis/Downloads/activator-1.3.3/repository/com.google.inject.extensions/guice-assistedinject/4.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-local: tried
[warn]   /home/travis/Downloads/activator-1.3.3/repository/com.google.inject.extensions/guice-assistedinject/4.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/inject/extensions/guice-assistedinject/4.0/guice-assistedinject-4.0.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/google/inject/extensions/guice-assistedinject/4.0/guice-assistedinject-4.0.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releasez: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.google.inject.extensions/guice-assistedinject/4.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.google.inject.extensions#guice-assistedinject;4.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      com.google.inject.extensions:guice-assistedinject:4.0
[warn]        +- com.typesafe.play:play_2.11:2.4.0
[warn]        +- com.typesafe.play:play-jdbc-api_2.11:2.4.0
[warn]        +- com.typesafe.play:play-jdbc_2.11:2.4.0
[warn]        +- com.typesafe.play:play-java-jdbc_2.11:2.4.0 (/home/travis/Documents/Play/doorway_rebuild/build.sbt#L9-14)
[warn]        +- com.typesafe.play:play-ebean_2.11:1.0.0 ((play.ebean.sbt.PlayEbean) PlayEbean.scala#L39)
[warn]        +- doorway_dms:doorway_dms_2.11:1.0-SNAPSHOT
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.google.inject.extensions#guice-assistedinject;4.0: not found
at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:291)
at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:188)
at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:165)
at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:155)
at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:155)
at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:132)
at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:57)
at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$4.call(Ivy.scala:65)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:65)
at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:127)
at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:124)
at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:155)
at sbt.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:165)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1369)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1365)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$87.apply(Defaults.scala:1399)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$87.apply(Defaults.scala:1397)
at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:37)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1402)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1396)
at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:60)
at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1419)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1348)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1310)
at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.google.inject.extensions#guice-assistedinject;4.0: not found
```

Here is my build.sbt

```
name := """doorway_dms"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava,PlayEbean)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs
)

// Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be  injected, the
// other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

I found this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework-dev/XfHR55R_tMY) detailing a similar problem, but from what I gather the original poster only had the issue on unstable connections. 
Any thoughts or ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by reinstalling jdk.

Answer (score 0):

Try run clean

or

remove the generated folders (target, project) and restart